# NSData -> UIImage -> NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, graphics, sdk

I have an `NSData` object, which contains RGB values for an image. I want to turn that into a `UIImage` (given the width and the height). Then I want to convert that `UIImage` back into an `NSData` object identical to the one I started with.

Please help me I've been trying for hours now.

Here are some things I've looked at/tried though probably didn't too them right cause it didn't work:

```
CGImageCreate
CGBitmapContextCreateWithData
CGBitmapContextGetData
CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef))
```

Thanks!

Here is my current code:

```
NSMutableData *rgb; //made earlier
double len = (double)[rgb length];
len /= 3;
len += 0.5;
len = (int)len;
int diff = len*3-[rgb length];
NSString *str = @"a";
NSData *a = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
for(int i =0; i < diff; i++) {
    [toEncode appendData:a]; //so if my data is RGBRGBR it will turn into RGBRGBR(97)(97)
}
size_t width = (size_t)len;
size_t height = 1;
CGContextRef ctx; 
CFDataRef m_DataRef;
m_DataRef = (__bridge CFDataRef)toEncode;
UInt8 * m_PixelBuf = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(m_DataRef); 
vImage_Buffer src;
src.data = m_PixelBuf;
src.width = width;
src.height = height;
src.rowBytes = 3 * width;
vImage_Buffer dst;
dst.width = width;
dst.height = height;
dst.rowBytes = 4 * width;
vImageConvert_RGB888toARGB8888(&src, NULL, 0, &dst, NO, kvImageNoFlags);
//    free(m_PixelBuf);
//    m_PixelBuf = dst.data;
//    NSUInteger lenB = len * (4/3);
/*
 UInt8 * m_Pixel = malloc(sizeof(UInt8) * lenB);
 int z = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < lenB; i++) {
 if(i % 4==0) {
 m_Pixel[i] = 0;
 } else {
 m_Pixel[i] = m_PixelBuf[z];
 z++;            
 }
 }*/
//    Byte tmpByte; 

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
/*
 ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(m_PixelBuf, 
 width, 
 height, 
 8, 
 4*width, 
 colorSpace, 
 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst ); 
 */
size_t w = (size_t)len;
ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(dst.data, 
                            w, 
                            height, 
                            8, 
                            4*width, 
                            colorSpace, 
                            kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst );     
CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx); 
UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 

CGContextRelease(ctx);
```

I get this error:`<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 324 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst.`

Comment: Describe your input `NSData` format in more detail.  Show us the *actual* code you tried, instead of vaguely describing it.

Comment: The format is just : R,G,B,R,G,B,R,G,B......
So for example I want to create a 100px by 100px image out of:
100 * 100 * 3 bytes stored in the nsdata object.

Comment: You also need to edit your question and paste in your actual code.

Answer (score 5):

TO UIImage from NSData:

```
[UIImage imageWithData:]
```

More on [UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

TO NSData from UIImage:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some.png"];
NSData *dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
```

More on [UIImageJPEGRepresentation()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: That only works for data that is already in some kind of standard (most likely compressed) image format (png, jpg...), but not for raw pixel data.

Answer (score 2):

The basic procedure would be to create a bitmap context using `CGBitmapContextCreateWithData` and then creating a `CGImageRef` from that with `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`. The parameters for creating the bitmap context depend on how your raw data is laid out in memory. Not all kinds of raw data are supported by Quartz.

The [documentation on `CGBitmapContextCreateWithData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreateWithData) is quite detailed, and this is the most challenging part, getting the `CGImageRef` from the context and wrapping that in a `UIImage` (`imageWithCGImage:`) is trivial afterwards.

Comment: Can I use CGBitmapContextCreate with a 3-channel image? My data is in RGB not RGBA format

Comment: Actually, how could I efficiently add an empty alpha channel to my data?
So for example if my data is currently: R,G,B,R,G,B,R,G,B turn it into 0,R,G,B,0,R,G,B,0,R,G,B

Comment: You can use the `vImageConvert_RGB888toARGB8888` function in the Accelerate framework to create a copy of your image data that includes an alpha channel. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/vImage_conversion/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: You cannot use `CGBitmapContextCreate` to create an RGB-format (24-bit-per-pixel) context.  iOS only supports 32-bit-per-pixel contexts and 8-bit-per-pixel contexts.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in RGB format, you will want to create a bitmap using `CGBitmapContextCreate` with `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB` and using `kCGImageAlphaNone`.

Comment: I tried, I get CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 24 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaNone;

Comment: Ahh right. Then create the bitmap using with alpha, but just skip the setting/reading the value for the alpha.

Comment: So you mean like kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst? Right now I am attempting @rob mayoff suggestion of using the vImageConvert_RGB888toARGB8888 function in the Accelerate framework

Answer (score 0):

The error stating that rowBytes needs to be at least 324; dividing that by 4 is 81 which implies that 'width' is smaller than 'w', and that w=81. The two values should match.

Try replacing width and w with a small number like 5 to validate this. I would also note that you should be allocating dst.data via malloc prior to calling vImageConvert_RGB888toARGB8888.

Consider using CGImageCreate() instead of creating a bitmapcontext:

```
// this will automatically free() dst.data when destData is dealloc
NSData *destData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:dst.data length:4*width*height];
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)destData);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width,
                                    height,
                                    8,                          //bits per component
                                    8*4,                        //bits per pixel
                                    4*width,                    //bytesPerRow
                                    colorSpace,                 //colorspace
                                    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst,
                                    provider,                   //CGDataProviderRef
                                    NULL,                       //decode
                                    false,                      //should interpolate
                                    kCGRenderingIntentDefault   //intent
                                    );
```